Is it possible to run decryption algorithm under homomorphic encryption
I have an idea to create DRM scheme on decentralized file sharing and I think it could utilize homomorphic encryption
What I am not sure is, are there homomorphic encryption algorithm (FHE?) that support nested encryption and decryption ?
I mean, to let the function hold encrypted of the private key, encrypt value with public key, then decrypt the encrypted value
Supposedly, if the homomorphic encryption is work like this diagram

Can we let the $Enc[x]$ be the encrypted key and $f()$ be the decryption function $decrypting(Enc_k(data),k) => data$ ?
Are there exist a homomorphic function $decrypting(Enc_k(data),Enc_0[k])$ that can return $Enc_0[data]$ ?
Because with this scheme, the server will never know the actual original data. So the owner can store and share the encrypted file anywhere. But only the client with encrypted key $Enc[k]$ can extract the value
Is this possible?

This is what Gentry's seminal work does. Calculate any circuit under encryption..

You can find many FHE implementation test their performance on AES ENC and DEC routines,
